# ODATA Service access on Iphone

Tags: ios, wcf, proxy, odata, svc

I want to access an WCF .svc service from my iphone application. It is an ODATA based service.
the samples from the ODATA sdk for iOS shows how to create proxy classes for the database schema using normal HTTP access. But my trouble is that my service is behind an SSL layer. SO I am getting a parsing error whenever i am trying to access to generate proxy classes using the ODATAGEN library present inside the OData sdk for iOS.

Can anyone help me regarding this. I have been using the ODatasdk version v1.3.

Thanks in advance.